# using a wire-frame shader on a plane how can i also fill in the squares with a solid color so that each square's color can be changed?

Tags: unity, shaders

[image: Shader applied to plane]

I'm not sure if using a shader is the best way for what I'm trying to achieve, but I would like to apply a color to each of the squares like in the picture and have the ability to change each color separately. I got the shader on this site: [Link to Shader site](http://www.shaderslab.com/demo-94---wireframe-without-diagonal.html)

```
Shader "Custom/Geometry/Wireframe"
{
Properties
{
    [PowerSlider(3.0)]
_WireframeVal("Wireframe width", Range(0., 0.5)) = 0.05
    _FrontColor("Front color", color) = (1., 1., 1., 1.)
    _BackColor("Back color", color) = (1., 1., 1., 1.)
    [Toggle] _RemoveDiag("Remove diagonals?", Float) = 0.
}
    SubShader
{
    Tags{ "Queue" = "Geometry" "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

    Pass
{
    Cull Front
    CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma geometry geom

    // Change "shader_feature" with "pragma_compile" if you want set this 
keyword from c# code
#pragma shader_feature __ _REMOVEDIAG_ON

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct v2g {
    float4 worldPos : SV_POSITION;
};

struct g2f {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 bary : TEXCOORD0;
};

v2g vert(appdata_base v) {
    v2g o;
    o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
    return o;
}

[maxvertexcount(3)]
void geom(triangle v2g IN[3], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream) {
    float3 param = float3(0., 0., 0.);

#if _REMOVEDIAG_ON
    float EdgeA = length(IN[0].worldPos - IN[1].worldPos);
    float EdgeB = length(IN[1].worldPos - IN[2].worldPos);
    float EdgeC = length(IN[2].worldPos - IN[0].worldPos);

    if (EdgeA > EdgeB && EdgeA > EdgeC)
        param.y = 1.;
    else if (EdgeB > EdgeC && EdgeB > EdgeA)
        param.x = 1.;
    else
        param.z = 1.;
#endif

    g2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[0].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(1., 0., 0.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[1].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(0., 0., 1.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[2].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(0., 1., 0.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
}

float _WireframeVal;
fixed4 _BackColor;

fixed4 frag(g2f i) : SV_Target{
    if (!any(bool3(i.bary.x < _WireframeVal, i.bary.y < _WireframeVal, 
[![Plane with Shader attached][1]][1]i.bary.z < _WireframeVal)))
    discard;

return _BackColor;
}

    ENDCG
}

    Pass
{
    Cull Back
    CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma geometry geom

    // Change "shader_feature" with "pragma_compile" if you want set this 
keyword from c# code
#pragma shader_feature __ _REMOVEDIAG_ON

#include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct v2g {
    float4 worldPos : SV_POSITION;
};

struct g2f {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float3 bary : TEXCOORD0;
};

v2g vert(appdata_base v) {
    v2g o;
    o.worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
    return o;
}

[maxvertexcount(3)]
void geom(triangle v2g IN[3], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream) {
    float3 param = float3(0., 0., 0.);

#if _REMOVEDIAG_ON
    float EdgeA = length(IN[0].worldPos - IN[1].worldPos);
    float EdgeB = length(IN[1].worldPos - IN[2].worldPos);
    float EdgeC = length(IN[2].worldPos - IN[0].worldPos);

    if (EdgeA > EdgeB && EdgeA > EdgeC)
        param.y = 1.;
    else if (EdgeB > EdgeC && EdgeB > EdgeA)
        param.x = 1.;
    else
        param.z = 1.;
#endif

    g2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[0].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(1., 0., 0.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[1].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(0., 0., 1.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_VP, IN[2].worldPos);
    o.bary = float3(0., 1., 0.) + param;
    triStream.Append(o);
}

float _WireframeVal;
fixed4 _FrontColor;

fixed4 frag(g2f i) : SV_Target{
    if (!any(bool3(i.bary.x <= _WireframeVal, i.bary.y <= _WireframeVal, 
i.bary.z <= _WireframeVal)))
    discard;

return _FrontColor;
}

    ENDCG
}
}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you look into how to do "Instancing", you not only can assign a Matrix for position, orientation etc, you can also add other attributes such as colour and transparency.   There are a number of tutorials and how to's out there on this, this should allow you to handle each square discreetly.

Comment: I don't think a shader is going to solve this problem. Use a bunch of quads.

Answer (score 0):

Share an idea for you.
Use shader can do that but maybe use `Plane` meshes is more simple .
Each grid is covered with a plane.You may change the plane color property of its material by what you desired. I kown you care about the performance.So please read this : [MaterialPropertyBlock](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

> MaterialPropertyBlock is used by Graphics.DrawMesh and
>   Renderer.SetPropertyBlock. Use it in situations where you want to draw
>   multiple objects with the same material, but slightly different
>   properties. For example, if you want to slightly change the color of
>   each mesh drawn.

At last, I supply a good example for this:

[The magic of Material Property Blocks](http://thomasmountainborn.com/2016/05/25/materialpropertyblocks/)

This is my first answer at GameDevelopment.I hope this could help you.